# Linux functions, why do they have number inside?

Tags: c, linux

for example execve(2) is the function of execve
login(1) is the function of login, what does the number means?

[image: execve]
[image: login]

Comment: because something like `printf(1)` and `printf(3)` are different. Compare the output of `man printf.1` and `man printf.3`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are the manual section numbers. From the [man manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html):

```
 The table below shows the section numbers of the manual followed
 by the types of pages they contain.

   1   Executable programs or shell commands
   2   System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
   3   Library calls (functions within program libraries)
   4   Special files (usually found in /dev)
   5   File formats and conventions, e.g. /etc/passwd
   6   Games
   7   Miscellaneous (including macro packages and conventions),
       e.g. man(7), groff(7)
   8   System administration commands (usually only for root)
   9   Kernel routines [Non standard]
```

Answer (score 0):

The number refers to the section of the man-page.

Some (most?) topics have entries in multiple sections, so the section number is used to differentiate them.
Foe example, there's a topic for login in the User Commands section (i.e., [login(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/login.1.html)) and in the Linux Programmer's Manual (i.e., [login(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/login.3.html)).